# Print function not working in iPython notebook

Tags: python

I'm new to Python. Having trouble printing data set in iPython notebook. Here's is a screenshot. Any thoughts?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lyCF.jpg)

Comment: There are no print statements there. To print something in python, you must call print(some_printable).

Answer (score 1):

As of Python 3, [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#map) returns an iterator, not a list. The problem in your code has nothing to do with print-- it's caused because you are expecting a list of lists, but instead you have a list of map iterators. To fix this, just call `list()` on each iterator or use a list comprehension instead of `map`.

```
fltLine = list(map(float, curLine))
```

OR (the equivalent, if not better)

```
fltLine = [float(x) for x in curLine]
```

Answer (score 0):

`print(list(map(list,dsn)))`

That should work.